# How do I call upon objects using dot notation that are nested in dictionaries?

Tags: python, class, object, dictionary

```
employees = {}         
employees["employeetest"]=employee(s.cell(3,0).value)
```

I want to store objects in a dictionary.
How do I call upon "employeetest" with dot notation?

I want to do this but with a list:

```
employee1 = employee(s.cell(3,0.value))
print(employee.job)
```

If I can't use a dictionary, how else can I dynamically create objects that I can call upon?

I'm sorry if this is a low quality post, I am new to programming.

Comment: It's not clear from your example what exactly you're trying to achieve. You've stored an object in the dict, using the key "employeetest". Now what is it that you want to be able to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the object with normal dict notation `employees["employeetest"]`, and then access the attributes of that object normally.

```
employeetest = employees["employeetest"]
print(employeetest.job)
```

The issue that you'll run into is that you can only assign one employee to `employees["employeetest"]`. You're going to have to figure out a better way to identify your employees within your `employees` dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
employees = type('obj', (object,), {})
employees["my_key"] = "my_value"
empleyees.my_key  # returns my_value
```